# Problems installing Manim

Tags: pip

I´ve followed all the steps to install manim, but I´m not able to finish the last step. I´m imputing the right command, but it´s not able to finish it.
`No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvcompiler' in numpy distutils; trying from distutils customize MSVCCompiler libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in` Then it proceeds to give the path to the file and say that it is no available
Edit, i´m doing the Installation on windows 7 and using Python 3.8.8 32 bits and I´m following the steps to directly install manim.

Comment: Please post more information. Which OS are you on (I am assuming windows?) Which python version are you running? What steps are you following for installing `manim`?

Answer (score 2):

I used the following code and was good to go:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org manimlib
```

Comment: isnt this the community version?